# Why doesn't CreateView pass the argument to the formsets?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Override form field queryset by passing additional argument (**employee_pk**) from `get_form_kwargs` method to `__init__` form method. I try 2 ways, both do not work.

First:

```
class SkillTestCreateView(AuthorizedMixin, CreateView):
    model = Skill
    form_class = SkillGroupCreateForm
    template_name = 'skill_create.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['employee_pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print(self.kwargs['pk']) --->   just for test print 4
        context = super(SkillTestCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SkillGroupCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.employee_pk = kwargs.pop('employee_pk', None) # 
        super(SkillGroupCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['technology'].required = False
        if self.employee_pk:
            self.fields['technology'].queryset = Technology.objects.exclude(skill__employee_id=self.employee_pk)
```

**Second:**

```
class SkillCreateView(AuthorizedMixin, CreateView):

model = Skill
form_class = SkillCreateForm
template_name = 'employee_info_create.html'

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update(employee_pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return kwargs
```

**forms.py**

```
class SkillCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, employee_pk=None, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       if employee_pk is not None:
           self.fields['technology'].queryset = Technology.objects.exclude(
               skill__employee_id=employee_pk
           )
```

Both return None

**upd**

I inherit 2 another forms from SkillGroupCreateForm

```
class SkillCreatePLanguageForm(SkillGroupCreateForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SkillCreatePLanguageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['technology'].queryset = self.fields['technology'].queryset.filter(group__name="Programming language")


class SkillCreateFrameworkForm(SkillGroupCreateForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SkillCreateFrameworkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['technology'].queryset = self.fields['technology'].queryset.filter(group__name="Framework")
```

**formset**

```
def get_extra_framework():
    return(Technology.objects.filter(group__name="Framework").count())


def get_extra_language():
    return(Technology.objects.filter(group__name="Programming language").count())


SkillFrameworkFormSet = modelformset_factory(Skill, form=SkillCreateFrameworkForm,
                                             max_num=get_extra_framework(), extra=get_extra_framework(), can_delete=False)

SkillPLanguageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Skill, form=SkillCreatePLanguageForm,
                                             max_num=get_extra_language(), extra=get_extra_language(), can_delete=False)
```

Comment: Are you sure `get_form_kwargs` is called? Perhaps it might help to add a `print` statement. Can you print the `kwargs` before it is returned to "inspect" what you pass to the form.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tested first way and when add `print self.kwargs['pk']`  at `get_context_data()` I got number 4. But when I add `print self.kwargs['pk']` at form like `    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.employee_pk = kwargs.pop('employee_pk', None)
        print(self.employee_pk)`  I got  6 returned variables `4
None
None
None
None
None
`

Comment: I believe in your "second time attempt" the issue lies when you try to `update` the `kwargs` dictionary in your `views.py`. I think you should do like: `kwargs.update({employee_pk=self.kwargs['pk']})`

Comment: @HigorRossato: no a dictionary takes kwargs for the update.

Comment: @HigorRossato return SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah I know but I thought it could be it. Thanks for reminding anyway :)

Comment: print kwarg from forms return {'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'instance': None}
{'auto_id': 'id_%s', 'prefix': 'form-0', 'error_class': <class 'django.forms.utils.ErrorList'>, 'use_required_attribute': False, 'empty_permitted': True}
.....
....
6 time `

Comment: @Jekson as Willem said it shouldn't be a problem but I forgot to add '' on my code I pasted here. If you wanna try It should be `kwargs.update({'employee_pk': self.kwargs['pk']})`

Comment: @Jekson: it looks like you create a form with the parameter, but you create the form multiple times...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I found a reason why the kwargs are output so many times. This is due to the fact that the form is used in the modelformet_factory.  If  use the second variant of code and set extra=0, I get the id I need once. But of course nothing is displayed in the template.

Comment: @Jekson: so you use the form in a formset? The current code does not seem to suggest that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I'm sorry, I didn't think that would affect it. I've extended the question

Comment: What if you use `kwargs.update(form_kwargs={'employee_pk': self.kwargs['pk']})` here? You can pass form kwargs to a formset, but with `form_kwargs` as a level of indirection.

Comment: I got an error  `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form_kwargs'` I made a screenshot for better understanding  http://joxi.net/8AneV8nHza3De2

Comment: Django's create/update generic views were not designed for formsets. I recommend against trying to modify them to handle formsets, as it leads to complicated code. You may find [`django-extra-views`](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/) useful - it has [generic formset views](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/formset-views.html).

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you for advice. I'm gonna trу.